# SQL different between sum(c1)*sum(c2) and sum(c1*c2)

Tags: sql

In SQL language what's the different results or performence between

```
sum(c1) * sum(c2) from t
```

and

```
sum(c1 * c2) from t
```

I use it to sum sales totals

```
select sum(price * quantity) as total from Bill
```

so what's the best choice?

Comment: Do you get different results?

Comment: Please don't spam-tag with every db platform.

Comment: vertical vs horizontal summations

Comment: Do you have zeroes in your data?  Are these values floating point or numeric?  Either of those conditions could result in differences.

Comment: c1*c2 occurs row by row,  sum(c1) occurs for the whole column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertical and Horizontal summations ... assuming no NULLS

```
declare @mytable table (a int, b int)

insert into @mytable 
values 
(1,1),
(2,3)


select * from @mytable

select sum(a) * sum(b) from @mytable  -- result is 12 .. vertical/column, summarize column first then multiply to other column

select sum(a*b) from @mytable  --- result is 7  .. horizontal/row, summarize the product of a and b
```

Comment: I use it to sum sales totals

**``select sum(price * quantity) as total from Bill`'**
so what's the best choice?

Comment: The per row calculation is what you choose for price*qty

Answer (score 1):

This is not a matter of SQL. It's just basic math. Assuming c1=(0,1) and c2=(2,3). Then:

```
sum(c1)*sum(c2) alias... (0+1)*(2+3) = 5
```

is **not** the same as:

```
sum(c1*c2)      alias... (0*2)+(1*3) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

NULLs and Zeros are one concern

```
Declare @YourTable table (C1 money,C2 money)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (100,10)
,(100,null)

Select sum(c1) * sum(c2)   -- 2000.00
 From @YourTable

Select sum(c1 * c2)        -- 1000.00
 From @YourTable
```